# SSIS deployement to Catalog with (.dtsConfig) FILE

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS project that copies data from 1 table to another, the destination table and target tables are passed through variables, I have created a config file to allow dynamic changing of the target table and destination tables names.I have now deployed the project to SSIS catalog but I have no idea where to get the XML config file to change the table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SSIS Catalog! Config files are gone, you have two great options - [Package Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters?view=sql-server-2017) and [Server Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/create-and-map-a-server-environment?view=sql-server-2014). Parameters can add flexibility to packages - one specify its value at package start. Environments will help with 'environment-dependent' settings like connection strings etc.
You can still use dtsConfig files in SSIS 2008 compatibility mode, but it is not practical and is not supported by SSIS Catalog.